# how can I fork Ethereum and turn it into my own sidechain how can I build my smart contracts in it?

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, nodes, sidechain, smart-contract

how can I copy Ethereum source code and node software client to modify the data structure to turn it into my own sidechain and how can I build smart contracts in the sidechain so that the sidechain can handle its own smart contracts on it and it has its own deployable sidechain node client software?

Comment: Tools like Brownies, Truffle,  Hardhat can fork any public blockchain and run it locally.  Such a functionality is often used for testing during development.  But you want to legit run your own ETH blockchain?